# Is there an API to remotely read a Windows machine's audit configuration?

Tags: windows, wmi, event-log, audit

I need to know, for each subcategory, whether it'll be audited on success, on failure, both, or none. This information is available locally via [AuditEnumerateSubCategories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), however there does not appear to be a means to access this same information remotely. Below is an example of the information I need to collect.

Can I get this through WMI? Or if not, by other means, assuming I have proper (admin) credentials to the target machine?

Again, to clarify, it's not the event log I need to read, it's the logging configuration.

```
  <security_state_change>AUDIT_SUCCESS</security_state_change>
  <security_system_extension>AUDIT_NONE</security_system_extension>
  <system_integrity>AUDIT_SUCCESS_FAILURE</system_integrity>
  <ipsec_driver>AUDIT_NONE</ipsec_driver>
  <other_system_events>AUDIT_SUCCESS_FAILURE</other_system_events>
  <logon>AUDIT_SUCCESS</logon>
  <logoff>AUDIT_SUCCESS</logoff>
  <account_lockout>AUDIT_SUCCESS</account_lockout>
  <ipsec_main_mode>AUDIT_NONE</ipsec_main_mode>
  <ipsec_quick_mode>AUDIT_NONE</ipsec_quick_mode>
  <ipsec_extended_mode>AUDIT_NONE</ipsec_extended_mode>
  <special_logon>AUDIT_SUCCESS</special_logon>
  <other_logon_logoff_events>AUDIT_NONE</other_logon_logoff_events>
  <file_system>AUDIT_NONE</file_system>
  <registry>AUDIT_NONE</registry>
  <kernel_object>AUDIT_NONE</kernel_object>
  <sam>AUDIT_NONE</sam>
  <certification_services>AUDIT_NONE</certification_services>
  <application_generated>AUDIT_NONE</application_generated>
  <handle_manipulation>AUDIT_NONE</handle_manipulation>
  <file_share>AUDIT_NONE</file_share>
  <filtering_platform_packet_drop>AUDIT_NONE</filtering_platform_packet_drop>
  <filtering_platform_connection>AUDIT_NONE</filtering_platform_connection>
  <other_object_access_events>AUDIT_NONE</other_object_access_events>
  <sensitive_privilege_use>AUDIT_NONE</sensitive_privilege_use>
  <non_sensitive_privlege_use>AUDIT_NONE</non_sensitive_privlege_use>
  <other_privlege_use_events>AUDIT_NONE</other_privlege_use_events>
  <process_creation>AUDIT_NONE</process_creation>
  <process_termination>AUDIT_NONE</process_termination>
  <dpapi_activity>AUDIT_NONE</dpapi_activity>
  <rpc_events>AUDIT_NONE</rpc_events>
  <audit_policy_change>AUDIT_SUCCESS</audit_policy_change>
  <authentication_policy_change>AUDIT_SUCCESS</authentication_policy_change>
  <authorization_policy_change>AUDIT_NONE</authorization_policy_change>
  <mpssvc_rule_level_policy_change>AUDIT_NONE</mpssvc_rule_level_policy_change>
  <filtering_platform_policy_change>AUDIT_NONE</filtering_platform_policy_change>
  <other_policy_change_events>AUDIT_NONE</other_policy_change_events>
  <user_account_management>AUDIT_SUCCESS</user_account_management>
  <computer_account_management>AUDIT_NONE</computer_account_management>
  <security_group_management>AUDIT_SUCCESS</security_group_management>
  <distribution_group_management>AUDIT_NONE</distribution_group_management>
  <application_group_management>AUDIT_NONE</application_group_management>
  <other_account_management_events>AUDIT_NONE</other_account_management_events>
  <directory_service_access>AUDIT_NONE</directory_service_access>
  <directory_service_changes>AUDIT_NONE</directory_service_changes>
  <directory_service_replication>AUDIT_NONE</directory_service_replication>
  <detailed_directory_service_replication>AUDIT_NONE</detailed_directory_service_replication>
  <credential_validation>AUDIT_NONE</credential_validation>
  <kerberos_ticket_events>AUDIT_NONE</kerberos_ticket_events>
  <other_account_logon_events>AUDIT_NONE</other_account_logon_events>
```

Comment: This patent (http://www.patents.com/us-7739721.html) discusses policy sub-categories, and provides a description of remote access API's to this information, but these API's do not appear to be implemented in any of the Vista system DLL's, et al.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few suggestions for you to look into are:

The [RSOP_AuditPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374873(v=VS.85).aspx) WMI class - It provides access to the settings related to auditing various types of events. One caveat, which may not be an issue for you, is that it is only supported on Windows XP and higher.

[LSA Policy Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722489(VS.85).aspx) - A set of Windows API functions that allow you to query policy information, including auditing, on a local or remote machine. The [LsaQueryInformationPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378313(v=VS.85).aspx) function will be of interest.

[Audit Policy Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375742(VS.85).aspx#audit_policy_functions) - They are only available in Windows Vista and higher. See this Code Project [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/QueryAuditPolicy.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I think the OP was asking how to retreive the information available locally via AuditEnumerateSubCategories over the network on a remote computer.  None of the above discuss how to do this...

Comment: @JamesHugard. Thanks for the feedback. However, I'm still not sure why you downvoted me. Especially since the OP accepted the answer, so it was of some use.

Comment: This is an old post however
RSOP_AuditPolicy - this is for the classic Audit Policy, not subcategories, to get this information you need to use AuditEnumerateSubCategories over a PowerShell remoting connection. This is how we do it for our network server documentation tool.